# Angularjs UI-Router: Incorrectly interpreting url path as paremeter in $urlRouterProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following setup in my `$stateProvider`:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main.newworkspace', {
        url: "/workspace/new",
        templateUrl: "views/main/newworkspace.html",
        controller: "NewWorkspaceCtrl"
    })
    .state('main.workspace', {
        url: "/workspace/:id",
        templateUrl: "views/main/workspace/main.html",
        controller: "WorkspaceCtrl",
        abstract: true
    })
    .state('main.workspace.dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "views/main/workspace/dashboard.html",
        controller: "DashboardCtrl"
    })
    .state('main.workspace.info', {
        url: "/info",
        templateUrl: "views/main/workspace/info.html",
        controller: "InfoCtrl"
    })
```

The following routes are now enabled for this app:

```
/workspace/new
/workspace/:id
/workspace/:id/dashboard
/workspace/:id/info
```

Because `/workspace/:id` is abstract, I would like it to automatically redirect to `/workspace/:id/dashboard`. I attempted to accomplish this by adding a `when()` to `$UrlRouterProvider`:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/workspace/:id', '/workspace/:id/dashboard');
```

So now it correctly redirects

```
/workspace/:id ------> /workspace/:id/dashboard
```

But also redirects `/workspace/new`

```
/workspace/new ------> /workspace/new/dashboard
```

Is there a quick fix for this? I also have tried determining if `$stateParam.id == 'new'` in the `$urlRouterProvider.when(...)` function call but $stateParam and $state.params are always empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should be able to give the special route priority similar way:

```
// when for the NEW state... will be matching first - and used
$urlRouterProvider.when('/workspace/new'
                       , function($state){$state.go('main.newworkspace');})
// other 'when' as needed...
$urlRouterProvider.when('/workspace/:id', '/workspace/:id/dashboard');
```

The first resloved `.when()` will win...

Comment: Thanks!  Worked for me.  Explicitly defining the higher-priority route with $urlRouteProvider.when('/foo/bar', function($state){$state.go('foo.bar');});

Comment: Is it possible to get $stateParams from the $urlRouterProvider? Because for me they are always empty and doing $stateParams.id doesn't work